# Django prefetch_related in property of inherited model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am running into an issue with `prefetch_related` on a property of an inherited model.

In **models.py** I have:

```
class Security(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    ...other fields

class Fund(Security):
    ...other fields

    @property
    def underlying_security(self):
        return self.maps_when_mapped.get().original_security

class SecurityToSecurityMap(models.Model):
    original_security = models.ForeignKey(Security, related_name="maps_when_original")
    mapped_security = models.ForeignKey(Security, related_name="maps_when_mapped")
```

and in **serializers.py**

```
class UnderlyingSecuritySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    name = serializers.CharField()

class FundSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    underlying_security = UnderlyingSecuritySerializer(read_only=True, allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Fund
        fields = ("id", "name", "underlying_security")
```

Now, I when I am querying fund objects:

```
queryset = Fund.objects.prefetch_related("maps_when_mapped__original_security")
```

Django ignores prefetching. Experimented with `Prefetch, tried moving property to the parent - no luck, still getting hundreds on queries. Any way this can be optimised?

I am using Django 2.2 with Postgres 11

**UPDATE 1**

After looking at the question, I suspect that problem is when I use `.get()` in property, it is immediately evaluated but then not sure how to fetch it without evaluation

Comment: What's the use of `get()` in property?

Comment: self.maps_when_mapped is a related manager and even though I know that it will result in maximum 1 object I still need to turn it into model. Is there another way to get from manager to model?

Comment: `.get()` will still call `filter()` on your queryset, you should prefetch `maps_when_mapped` ordered (this is just so your call to `first` doesn't trigger a new query to order the queryset) and access it with `.first()`, you can do so by using `Prefetch`